# How to nest static method invocations in Spring Expression Language in a Spring config file?

Tags: spring, guava, spring-el

I want to inject a guava [Predicate](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) into my bean, which should be an [equalto](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#equalTo%28T%29) inside a [not](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#not%28com.google.common.base.Predicate%29).

I tried this:

```
<bean id="bla" class="something">
    <property name="indexPredicate" value="#{T(com.google.common.base.Predicates).not(T(com.google.common.base.Predicates).equalTo(145028) )}" />
</bean>
```

But it throws exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException:
>   EL1049E:(pos 36): Unexpected data after '.': 'not(!)'

***Spring 3.0.5, Guava 11.0.2***

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently SpEL thinks you mean [the Operator `not`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operators). However, I don't see any way to escape or disambiguate that in the documentation. Perhaps you need to file a feature request for that.

Alternatively, here is the pre-3.0 factory-method approach. It's horrible, I know, but it might be an acceptable workaround in your case:

```
<property name="indexPredicate">
    <bean class="com.google.common.base.Predicates" factory-method="not">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.google.common.base.Predicates"
                  factory-method="equalTo">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="java.lang.Integer" factory-method="valueOf">
                        <constructor-arg value="145028" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9992. Thanks for the answer. Works fine.